# How to debug xcode slow compiling?

Tags: xcode, swift

Im looking in the report navigator for the process that is slowing down the compiler, and it shows that a ViewController is taking more than 4 MINUTES to compile, and I have read that if I copy the transcript to terminal and hit CTRL-\ it will show me the line that is causing the compiler to freeze, but it doesnt show me anything
Is it because my keyboard is in Spanish?

Please help me every time I need to build I have to wait 4 minutes!

Im using Swift 2.0 and xcode 7.0 before I updated to Swift 2.0 everything was working fine

Comment: Umm can we see the view controller?

Comment: @ BenKnoble Do you want me to upload all the file?

Comment: Uh no. Post the relevant code.

Comment: If its too large well maybe thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find out what was slowing down the compiling I had a long array

```
let correctas = [
              /*Quimica*/["S","Astato","Un ión con carga positiva","Un ión con carga negativa","Una partícula con carga negativa","Una partícula con carga positiva","118","Hidrógeno","Ag","Sólido, Liquido, Gaseoso, Plasma","Especie","Taxonomía","Hipótesis","Observación"]
              /*Matematicas*///[respuestas[1][0]]
              ]
```

All I needed to add was

```
let correctas = [
              /*Quimica*/["S","Astato","Un ión con carga positiva","Un ión con carga negativa","Una partícula con carga negativa","Una partícula con carga positiva","118","Hidrógeno","Ag","Sólido, Liquido, Gaseoso, Plasma","Especie","Taxonomía","Hipótesis","Observación"]
              /*Matematicas*///[respuestas[1][0]]
              ] as NSArray
```